# Is there a way that I can have a file download within the success function of an ajax call?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, download

I have a site, and users can select data that they want to view. What I want is to dynamically create a file on the server side, and then have it download for the user in the success function of the ajax call. 
What I currently have is a button

```
<div class='col-md-12 text-center'>
    <button class='btn btn-link' id='download-data-file'>Download Data File</button>
</div>
```

which when clicked should trigger the ajax call to create the file.
something like

```
$.ajax({
url: '/createDataFile/',
method: 'POST',
data: data,
datatype: 'json',
success: function(data, status, xhr){
    //Here Is where I am uncertain as to how to download the file for the user
    },
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    //Some error code
});
```

For the purpose of this just assume that data is already a json.

There are a few things that I am uncertain of. 1. within my server side code (which is python) Should I return the file object that I create, or should I save the file to my local disk and then return the filename of the local file. 2. Within the ajax success function, how could I download the file that I just created for the user?

For clarity, I do not need any assistance with the creation of the file, just with actually downloading it for the user

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create anchor tag with `download` attribute

Remove `dataType:'JSON'`

Use `responce` from ajax call in `anchor` tag to download. Add anchor tag to body and click on it.

```
success: function(data, status, xhr){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("download","filename.json");
    a.setAttribute("href","data:application/json,"+data);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    //document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```js
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("download","fname.json");
a.setAttribute("href","data:application/json,{ 'num' : 5 }");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
console.log('Downloaded successfully!');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll Try that.

Comment: So I should save the file I create locally?

Comment: Or should I return the file object in the data response?

Comment: The whole point of this is that it doesn't matter if it's saved locally (locally? On the server? on the client PC? assuming on the server) or not - the data downloaded into `success:` can be from anywhere, the data is then placed in a `<a href="data:..."` and clicked, forcing the browser to present the save dialog / auto save depending on browser settings.

Comment: @wilmoskal if you want to save file on server then you have to write code in `/createDataFile/` file. Our anchor tag just downloading response from server as `filename.json`, no matter response is json data or not,just downloading as `.json` extension.